# How to handle on Selenium Chromedriver to select certificate popup confirmation?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, certificate

*How to handle on Selenium Chromedriver to select certificate popup confirmation? I am automating tests using selenium chromewebdriver 94. Whenever I launch the site, I get a certificate selection popup like the one below.

Detail: I doing that with no adm rights, so I cannot just regedit a key on "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls" to ignore this.*

[select certificate screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Inl.png)

*I'm already try this but not worked:*

```
case "chrome":
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", WebDriverFactory.getChromeDriverBinary());
    ChromeOptions chromeoptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeoptions.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    chromeoptions.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
    chromeoptions.addArguments("start-maximized");

    chromeoptions.addArguments("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
    chromeoptions.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking");
    chromeoptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    chromeoptions.addArguments("--incognito");
    chromeoptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");

    DesiredCapabilities dcChrome = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    dcChrome.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
    dcChrome.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    dcChrome.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);

    return new ChromeDriver(chromeoptions);
```

*It's not working even if I tried Chrome Headless.
Somebody can help?*

Comment: Not sure if still working solution, I achieved it few years ago. Create manulay new chrome profile. Import your desired certificate file and set up to always use the imported one. Finaly launch selenium with the specific profile.

Comment: I will try that one, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can´t automatically select the certificate in the box because this popup window come from Windows.
Sorry for the other awser but din´t saw the Detail.
So in your case maybe you want to try something like [FlaUI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FlaUI.UIA3/), that help you to move you mouse cursor to the button OK on popup.
We in my time we use that but, when you logout the server or let the computer hibernate the FlaUI stop to work because windows shut down the mouse API.
So for this solution works you need let you computer on util the process end.